# Get online users facebook api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

How can i get list of 20 random ONLINE users on my friendlist @ Facebook, in their API?

Cannot find anything in the docs about select * from users where online = 1 'ish

```
FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) { 
    if(response.data) {
        $.each(response.data,function(index,friend) {
            //friend.id;
        });
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using FQL, you can easily get at this data -

```
SELECT uid,name,online_presence FROM user WHERE
  online_presence = 'active'
  AND uid IN (
    SELECT uid2 FROM friend where uid1 = me()
  ) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 20
```

Bare in mind that you'll need the `friends_online_presence` permission to see the users friend's chat status.